# Is it possible to include HTML embeds like Twitter on the WYSIWYG section of the CKEditor in D7?

Tags: wysiwyg, theming

I have staff writers who want to include embedded tweets in their articles. However, they don't know HTML and aren't able to use the "source" section of the editor.

Is there a way to embed the HTML inside the WYSIWYG side? Something like:

Regular text and photos

{{copied twitter embed code}}

More regular text and photos

...is what I'm looking to provide them. They're able to copy and paste the code as above, their struggle is finding the correct spot in the "source" section.